# Can mass still be observed in our universe after moving from a black-hole to a white-hole?

Tags: black-holes, mass, astrophysics, loop-quantum-gravity, white-holes

This question is based on the recent papers on LQG black-holes by Abhay Ashtekar. [Quantum extension of the Kruskal spacetime](http://arxiv.org/abs/1806.02406) and [Quantum Transfiguration by Kruskal Black Holes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1806.00648)

**When mass moves from one asymptotic region to another, can this mass still be observed as gravitation in the initial region (our universe)?**

If not, can it be the case that some black holes lose more mass than they accrete?

Comment: Do you want a standard GR answer, or are you asking for an interpretation of these LQG papers? In GR, the black hole and white hole regions  arise when you do the maximal extension of the Schwarzschild spacetime, which is a highly artificial mathematical construction. They don't represent the realistic spacetime of a black hole that forms by astrophysical collapse, and by definition we can't talk about moving mass out of one and into the other. If mass was flowing through a horizon, that would be astrophysical collapse, which is not Schwarzschild.